How to remove broken deck screws?
Trying to remove old decking screws from deck boards that are rotted and need replaced. Problem is that when I try to remove a screw, the screw snaps and then just spins in the hole and won't back-out... What to do?

Use a three foot pry/wrecking bar and pull the boards off.
Don't waste time with the screws.
Can either hammer the screws in or pull them out like nails after.

If you are replacing the boards, remove what screws you can, then just pull the boards up with a crowbar. (you are trashing them anyway.) The broken screws will come out with the boards.
Once all the boards are removed, any screw bodies remaining in the joists can be pulled out with locking grip pliers, or cut them even with the joists. Sometimes hammering to the side makes them break.
Trying to remove the screws spinning in the deck boards is a waste of time.

The other answers are correct in that you should not bother. But let's assume you want to remove the screws anyway.
Use a small pry bar, something like the ESTWING Pro Claw Nail Puller. It's small enough to dig into the wood. Then, once you have a grip on the head of the screw, use a screwdriver to pull it out. The pulling motion for the prybar is usually good enough to force the screw to get a bite on the wood and come out.
If the screws snap, just wait until you remove the board, then grab the top of each screw with a vise-grip, and turn them.
Or you can go medieval and get a Crescent nail puller.

I am not medieval, but they do work well for sunken heads.

The answers assume the joists into which the screws are driven are also in poor condition though.
